# How to add a filed in multiple layer in QGIS using python

Tags: python, qgis

I have 10 vector layers in QGIS. I want to add a field 'City', character varying in each of the layers using python. I have tried to add in a single layer but it is not working.

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.addAttribute([QgsField('City', text)])

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56826/how-to-add-a-column-in-qgis-via-python

Comment: This answer could work for you:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34974/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-add-calculated-fields